# Extending geodesics on a surface gives geodesics.. why?

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic

> Just as a line segment in the plane can be extended indefinitely in either direction by laying down overlapping segments, so too can a geodesic be extended on a curved surface, and this extension is unique.
>
> Tristan Needham Visual Differential Geometry

The intuition given later was that the surface in a way decides how the segment bends but could a more 'careful' intuition be given? In sense, I want something that is more specific as to what is happening.

Comment: Take the universal cover.

Comment: a geodesic is defined locally, so extending locally a geodesic into a geodesic gives a global geodesic

Comment: The claim made by this book is simply false: Yes, extension is unique (if it exists) but  geodesics in general cannot be "extended indefinitely": You have to add the assumption that  the metric is complete. My suggestion is to read a different textbook, one that will not lead you astray. For instance, do Carmo's "Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces."